# Cannot Delete file if file renamed on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have renamed my uploaded file on server, when i try to delete my image through dropzone.js the file does not get deleted because it is renamed.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  url: baseUrl+"/img/upload/store",
  params: {
    _token: token,
  },
  success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest){

  },

  removedfile: function(file) {

    var name = file.upload.filename;
    jQuery.ajax({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      },
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{ url("delete") }}',
      data: {filename: name},
      success: function (data){
        console.log("File has been successfully removed!!");
      },
      error: function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }});
    var fileRef;
    return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ?
        fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;

  },

});
```

Comment: I assume you're renaming it on the server side? If so, you could send the new file name back in the response to the upload so that you can use that instead of the default file name? With this, you would get the new file name back in the `data` from the `success()` method

Comment: yes i am renaming on the server, i have tried to return new name using return response()->json(['success'=>'200','imagesname'=>$image]); but i didn't know ho i can get and change the old name of the image to new name

Comment: Did you know you can also rename the file directly within Dropzone before uploading too?

Comment: yes but i want to rename it from server

Comment: Ok well in the success method, you should be getting the uploaded file back as the first argument (what you currently have as data) and the second argument would be the new name you send back (what you currently have as textStatus). 
With this, you could loop the current files in the Dropzone, finding the the correct file out of the list based on the `file` you get back as a first argument in the response, and then change its name accordingly. So that when you press delete, it will have the right name

Comment: yes i am getting new name in text status is there any way i can set this new name to my dropzone image delete button

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following:

In the success method, you should be getting the uploaded file back as the first argument (what you currently have as `data`) and the second argument would be the new name you send back (what you currently have as `textStatus`).

With this, you could loop the current files in the Dropzone, finding the the correct file out of the list based on the file you get back as a first argument in the response, and then change its name accordingly. So that when you press delete, it will have the right name

Please consider the following modified **pseudo code** which assumes you're sending back the new file name from the server.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
   addRemoveLinks: true, 
   url: baseUrl+"/img/upload/store",
   params: {
    _token: token,
   },
  success: function (fileSentToServer, newFileName){
   // Access the current files in the list/dropzone
   var fileList =  myDropzone.files;
   // Loop over
   fileList.forEach(file => {
     //Find the corresponding file in the list you just uploaded
     if(file.name == fileSentToServer.name) {
       //Rename it
       file.name = newFileName
     }
   })
  }, 

 removedfile: function(file) {
    // This name should now be the renamed version
    var name = file.upload.filename;
    jQuery.ajax({...

 },

});
```

It's also possible you may not even need the loop if the `file` param returned in the success method is a direct reference to the file in the file list.

Comment: I'm getting following error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#<File>' in the success method

Comment: Ok well instead of `file.name = newFileName` try `file.newName = newFileName`. Then in the `removedFile` method, use `var name = file.upload.newName`; I can only do so much as I can't edit your project and see the responses for myself, but you should have the answer here in order to figure out the last little bit